# KendoUI Autocomplete - Change event not firing when selecting the same thing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, autocomplete, jquery-events

KendoUI Autocomplete isn't allowing me to select the same **item twice in a row**. If I select an item, then select another, it will of course work, but not back-to-back.

By placing `this.trigger('change')` in the **select** method of `kendoAutoComplete({})`, it will work if you *click* on the item from the list itself, **BUT** if you type in the same thing and push *Enter*, it doesn't trigger the change event.

1. Type Anne, click on it (notice it adds it to the body (change event fired))
2. Try it again (nothing happens)

Just some example code: **[jsFiddle EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eruRt/1)**

```
var autoComplete = $("#input").kendoAutoComplete({
    // other methods...
    select: function (e) {
        console.log('---SELECT---');
        
        // this will work if we select the same thing and SELECT the item 
        // from the the dropdown list,
        //  ** but if we push ENTER, it won't trigger this
        
        //this.trigger('change'); // <--
    },
    change : function (e) {
        console.log(' >> CHANGE');
        $('body').append('<br>' + this.value());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After returning back to this problem, the issue was resolved by simply making the value of the kendoAutoComplete nothing.

Example:

```
$('#kendoID').data('kendoAutoComplete').value('');

// I have this at the end of the .change() event
// Lets you keep adding the same item
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit weird true, but the documentation says : Change : "Fired when the value of the widget is changed by the user." Which means once you type in Anne and press enter the value of the control is set to "Anne", once you type in Anne again and press enter the value is still the same, so no change no event. By placing the trigger into select that sounds to me as a different event > fire when selected.